# Why is orderby meta_value_num not working for get_posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm adding a rating score via a post meta value, and would like to sort the results of get_posts by this value (in this example, descending so the top scores appear at the top).

```
$top_rated_psychics = get_posts(array(
   'post_type'     => 'psychic',
   'numberposts'   => 3,
   'meta_key'      => 'psychic_score_average',
   'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
   'order'         => 'DESC'
));
```

But what's being output, seems to not be focusing on the score, but instead doing it alphabetically by Title?

e.g.

Mi (Score 4.5)
Mo (Score 4)
Ni (Score 4.5)

(I am expecting to see the Mo (with the score of 4) last in the list)

How can I identify what's wrong? Does ordering by meta_value_num not work with get_posts?

Comment: Guessing it currently tries to parse those text values as integers - try adding `'meta_type' => 'DECIMAL',`

Comment: That's an interesting discovery @CBroe, I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to make any difference though

Comment: It should work the same for `get_posts` as it does with `WP_Query` - so pass those arguments to the latter, and see what result that gets you. (Check the `$posts` property contents afterwards.)

Comment: The query for ordering just doesn't seem to change anything no matter if it's get_posts or with wp_query. It' seems to be stuck on ordering by title.

Comment: If I change the params to use orderby title and order to DESC, I see them still ordered from A-Z by title

Comment: That would not make much sense ... Are you sure you are actually inspecting the _correct_ query result there?

Comment: Absolutely certain. In a very simple example of even using get_posts to order by title, that isn't working. It feels like there's something wrong with get_posts.

Comment: And the actual database content of those `psychic_score_average` entries is what?

Comment: It's possible there is a filter that is changing the sort order. Can you try your query on a copy of the existing site, deactivating all plugins and using a default theme? Or you could try a tool like [Query Monitor](https://querymonitor.com/) to investigate filters.

Comment: @Caleb you were right, I had a pre_get_posts filter going on which was interrupting stuff! Argh!